# Error al utilizar Xgboost: "No visible GPU is found for XGBoost"

Tags: python, machine-learning

Estoy generando un modelo de Machine Learning en Python y al intentar correr un modelo con Xgboost el notebook me arroja un error:

```py
model = create_model('xgboost',max_depth = 12, learning_rate=0.5, tree_method='gpu_hist')
```

```
XGBoostError: [14:48:03] ../src/gbm/gbtree.cc:588: Check failed: common::AllVisibleGPUs() >= 1 (0 vs. 1) : No visible GPU is found for XGBoost.
```

No sé como poder solucionar este error, si alguien sabe que puedo hacer le agradeceré!

Comment: Acabo de realizr una búsqueda rápida y segun la respuesta que dan en esta discusión:https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/no-visible-gpu-is-found-setting-gpu-id-to-1/2034/3, el problema puede estar relacionado con los drivers de la GPU de tu maquina virtual o sistema operativo, intenta ejecutar alguna aplicacion que haga use de la GPU como PyTorch, si esque lo tienes. Espero que te sirva de algo :)

Answer (score 0):

El error podría ser un problema con la versión de los CUDA drivers de tu placa. Si usas una placa Nvidia y ese error también los obtienes en otros modelos implementados que requieran de CUDA GPU's entonces te recomiendo actualizar tus drivers con [esta](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11.2.0-download-archive) versión.